# Can't get Windows Overlay icons to work in TListView

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

Using Borland C++ Builder 2009 I can display overlay icons in a `TListView` object, using my own `TImageList`.

However I also need this to work with the Windows icons.  Showing those icons is not a problem, but I can't get Overlay icons to work (yet).

Here's what I do (not complete and code lifted out of a bigger project, but it should illustrate the question properly) :

During Init:

```
SHFILEINFO info ;
SmallSystemIconsList->Handle = SHGetFileInfo( L"",
                                            0,
                                            &info,
                                            sizeof(info),
                                            SHGFI_ICON |
                                            SHGFI_SMALLICON |
                                            SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX |
                                            SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX
                                            ) ;
DestroyIcon(info.hIcon) ;`
```

Everytime I want to know the index of an icon:

```
SHFILEINFO info ;
SHGetFileInfo(             MyFileName.c_str(),
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            &info,
                            sizeof(SHFILEINFO) ,
                            SHGFI_ICON |
                            SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES |
                            SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX
                            ) ;
DestroyIcon(info.hIcon) ;

// TListItem *ListItem
ListItem->ImageIndex    = (info.iIcon & 0x00FFFFFF) ;
ListItem->OverlayIndex  = (info.iIcon >> 24) - 1;
```

I notice that the proper values are being passed during testing.  For instance `ListItem->OverlayIndex` is assigned value 2 when the Filename is 'something.**lnk**'.

But the overlay icon is not showing.  I'm sure I'm missing something.  To get overlay icons to work with my own `TImageList` objects I had to call `ImageList->Overlay()`.  I wonder if I need to do the same with the Windows list, but I'm not sure what values to use then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay index returned by `SHGetFileInfo()` is 1-based, but the `TListItem::OverlayIndex` property expects a 0-based index, which it then converts to 1-based when updating the list item using the Win32 API.  So you need to subtract 1 when assigning the `OverlayIndex`:

```
ListItem->OverlayIndex  = (info.iIcon >> 24) - 1;
```

You DO NOT need to call `TImageList::Overlay()` when using a system image list.

**Update**: your subclass needs to look for the `CN_NOTIFY` message instead of `WM_NOTIFY`.  `WM_NOTIFY` is delivered to the ListView's *parent window* and reflected back to the ListView as `CN_NOTIFY` by the VCL.  Also, you need to use a *reference* when declaring your local `LVITEM` variable, otherwise you are modifying a *copy* instead of the *original* `LVITEM` that is in the message data.  Also, when assigning `item.state` and `item.stateMask`, you need to use the `|=` operator to *append* your overlay values to them instead of *replacing* the existing values that were assigned by the default handler.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::LVNewWindowProc(Messages::TMessage &Msg)
{
    if (LVOldWindowProc) LVOldWindowProc(Msg);
    if ((Msg.Msg == CN_NOTIFY) &&
        (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(Msg.LParam)->code == LVN_GETDISPINFOW))
    {
        LV_ITEM &item = reinterpret_cast<LV_DISPINFO*>(Msg.LParam)->item;
        TListItem *ListItem = ListView1->Items->Items[item.iItem];

        item.mask |= LVIF_STATE;
        item.state |= INDEXTOOVERLAYMASK(ListItem->OverlayIndex + 1);
        item.stateMask |= LVIS_OVERLAYMASK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, unfortunately that doesn't work either ?  I don't get to see any overlay icons, not just the wrong ones.  Thanks for the fix but anything else I may need to do to actually see the overlay icons ?

Comment: I assure you, it DOES work, because I tested it before I posted it here, and I did see the correct overlay icon appear.

Comment: Right, is this with a 'new' TListView object in a a new test project (aka default settings) ?  I'll try that as well.  I'm doing this in old existing code and I wonder if a setting in my ListView object is messing with things ?

Comment: Yes, I had tested it with a new project.

Comment: Hi Remy.  Finally I was able to revisit this and do some testing of my own.  I have traced the issue back to the **virtual** use of ListView in my implementation: `ListView->OwnerData = true ;`
In non-virtual mode I get the overlay icons as well, but when I change Ownerdata it doesn't work.
Any idea how to work around that ?

Comment: `TListView` does not support overlay images in virtual mode. Although `TListItem.OverlayIndex` will accept and store a new value, `TListItem` will not notify Windows that a new value has been assigned, and `TListView` will not provide that value to Windows in reply to the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification (which triggers the `TListView.OnData` event). You would have to subclass the `TListView` to handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification directly so you can populate overlay info in the notification's `LVITEM` structure (I have tested it, and overlays do work in virtual mode at the Win32 layer).

Comment: This is a known and long-standing issue with `TListView` and is still open in QC: [#55905 
TListview overlay images not drawn with OwnerData](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=55905).

Comment: Thanks !  I have `TListView` subclassed already to deal with sort arrows so I can use that code but I'm not sure how to do what you suggest ?  What is the Msg.Msg I should check for and how do I manipulate what is sent to Windows ?

Comment: See [QC #55905](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=55905), it has an example workaround.  The only downside to it is that the `OnData` event handler gets triggered twice per notification - once by `inherited`, and once by `Items[iItem]`.  To avoid that, you would have to skip `inherited` and handle the entire notification manually (see `TListView`'s source code for how it handles `LVN_GETDISPINFO`).

Comment: I'm not getting there TBH using existing subclass code (to show sort arrows). I don't know how you get iItem (now testing with hard coded overlay index 2), I don't know what the `inherited` is and I don't have access to the `TListView` code.  I put my test code in the original Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78477/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-peter).

Comment: Thanks for the code example in your answer.  It works.  OnData() is indeed called a lot.  I'll have to figure that one out as well then.

Comment: I'm having a weird problem with this functionality.  Posted as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466574/virtual-listview-items-get-wrong-content-when-hovering-over-them-from-bottom