# (Virtual) ListView items get wrong content when hovering over them, from bottom to top

Tags: c++, c++builder

I use C++ Builder 2009 and have implemented a Listview virtually.

Recently I learned of an issue that (so far) only happens for 3 people out of thousands. (Obviously there must be more instances, but they remain unreported so far).

What happens is that when the user hovers over the items in the ListView control, from bottom to top, the items in the list change.
Since the control is implemented virtually the software provides the information via an event and for 'a' reason the software gets the wrong index to work with when hovering from bottom to top.

See this little video to understand the behaviour better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNZkaBH24PY

I have been searching for a reason, on and off, for some time, hampered by the fact that I cannot repeat this problem myself, so I needed to send special builds to 1 of the 3 willing to help.  And I was finally able to pinpoint it to the use of Overlay icons !

I assign an icon to the items in the list by asking Windows what icon is relevant via `SHGetFileInfo`

The event:

```
void __fastcall TFinder::ListViewData(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item)
{
DListView->OnData(Item, DirInListView->Object(Item->Index)) ;
}
```

Code called by the event:

```
HANDLE ObjectDisplayInListView::OnData (TListItem *ListItem, DataObject *Object)
{

ListItem->Data      = (void*) Object ;

ListItem->Caption   = String(Object->DisplayName().c_str()) ;

if (!SystemIconsSet)
    {
    ListItem->ImageIndex    = Object->Icon() ;
    ListItem->OverlayIndex  = Object->IconOverlay() ;
    }
else
    {
    int Icon = SystemIcon(Object) ;
    ListItem->ImageIndex    = (Icon & 0x00FFFFFF) ;
    ListItem->OverlayIndex = (Icon >> 24) - 1 ;
    }

ListItem->Cut           = Object->IconGreyed() ;
ListItem->StateIndex    = Object->IconState() ;

return (HANDLE) ListItem ;
}
```

// The SystemIcon() routine:

```
int ObjectDisplayInListView::SystemIcon (DataObject *Object)
{
// SHFILEINFO info ; The class declared one will do !

info.hIcon = NULL ; // Just making sure

DWORD Res = SHGetFileInfoW( Object->DisplayName().c_str(),
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            &info,
                            sizeof(SHFILEINFO) ,
                            SHGFI_ICON |
                            SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES |
                            SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX
                                ) ;
DestroyIcon(info.hIcon) ; 

return info.iIcon ;
}
```

The subclass code (which can be removed completely and the problem still exists !!)

```
void __fastcall TFinder::LVNewWindowProc(Messages::TMessage &Msg)
{
if( LVOldWindowProc ) LVOldWindowProc( Msg );
if (Msg.Msg == WM_NOTIFY) // Sort arrows
    {
    // Not relevant for this Q but added since it is in my code
    switch(((LPNMHDR)Msg.LParam)->code)
        {
        case HDN_ENDTRACKA:
        case HDN_ENDTRACKW:
        case HDN_ITEMCHANGEDA:
        case HDN_ITEMCHANGEDW:
            {
            if(((LPNMHDR)Msg.LParam)->hwndFrom == ListView_GetHeader(ListView->Handle))
                {
                if (ObjInListView && dynamic_cast<FileDirObject*>(ObjInListView) && ListView->Items->Count)
                    {
                    SetSortArrow(SortingTypeToDesignColumn(UISortingType), UISortingDirection) ; // Show the arrow based on what sorting was used
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
        }
    }
else if (Msg.Msg == CN_NOTIFY && Platform > OS_PLATF_WINXP) 
    {                          
    if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(Msg.LParam)->code == LVN_GETDISPINFOW)
        {
        LV_ITEM &item = reinterpret_cast<LV_DISPINFO*>(Msg.LParam)->item ; 
        int  OverlayIndex = -1 ;

        TListItem *ListItem = ListView->Items->Item[item.iItem] ;
        if (ListItem) OverlayIndex = ListItem->OverlayIndex ;

        if (OverlayIndex >= 0)
            {
            item.mask |= LVIF_STATE ;
            item.state |= INDEXTOOVERLAYMASK(OverlayIndex + 1) ;
            item.stateMask |= LVIS_OVERLAYMASK ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented this based on an older question, asked here as well: [Can't get Windows Overlay icons to work in TListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110297/cant-get-windows-overlay-icons-to-work-in-tlistview)

To be more precise, this function has been working great for me for over 10 years, but about a year ago I added `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX` as well

The issue, as explained and as can be seen in the video, disappears entirely when I simply and only remove `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX` from the function call.
For whatever reason also asking for the overlay icon, causes the weird behaviour.

Even when I completely disable the `CN_NOTIFY` message subclassing that goes along with this functionality (see: [Can't get Windows Overlay icons to work in TListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110297/cant-get-windows-overlay-icons-to-work-in-tlistview) ) but call SHGetFileInfo() **with** `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX`, the problem happens !

Does anybody have an idea what this could be ?
A solution could be to not ask for the overlay icon on these problematic systems, but then I need to find a way to actually detect that the problem is going to happen (or is happening) somehow.

Comment: Please show your actual ListView code.  From the video, it looks like this MIGHT be another case of 0-based vs 1-based indexing that you might not be handling correctly again. Or maybe you are not handling the `info.psf->iIcon` field correctly. Hard to say without seeing some actual code.

Comment: PS. this works correctly on most systems.  I believe the index is correct.  In fact, in this implementation I could leave the returned overlay index as is, but just to avoid VCL doing something funky internally I subtract and later add 1 again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I take it you're not seeing anything that could cause the mentioned behaviour ?  I wonder if this is a driver and/or VCL ?

Comment: The code is there, no input so far.  If all is normal with this code, pertaining to the issue, I will delete the entire question.  No point leaving this here then.

Comment: Did you verify that `DirInListView->Object()` is always returning the correct `DataObject*` even during hovering? Why is `LVNewWindowProc()` not calling a default handler for unhandled messages? Can you re-write `LVNewWindowProc()` to use a `DataObject*` directly and not use `TListView->Items->Item[]`? Using `Item[]` triggers `OnData`, and internally a virtual `TListView` reuses the same private `TListItem` everytime it needs access to a physical `TListItem`  so I like to avoid `OnData` whenever possible. I use it for visual rendering, but go to my datasource directly whenever code needs data

Comment: `DirInListView->Object()` always returns the correct object yes.  The array code behind it powers the entire project.  Almost everything would be going wrong if this part was not working right.  As far as I can tell TListItem *Item is always correctly provided by VCL, it certainly is on the majority of systems.  It's also hard to relate to `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX`.  Bear in mind that **only** removing `SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX` fixes it on those systems.

Comment: `LVNewWindowProc()` has a default handler, I added it to above code.  It fell off when I copy pasted because I removed the handling of another message, for sort-arrow display purposes.  Now added as well for completeness.

Comment: I need the ListItem because that's where the Overlay icon gets stored.  I have no actual space in my own object to keep track of it.  However, I use caching to reduce the overhead that you explain. In OnData, first the cache is checked and used.  Also in the NewWindowProc code.  I removed the caching code to keep the Q clean but I have tested it without caching extensively as well and I can confirm it's not in that code either. Caching or not makes no difference.  But the actual code that I use (with caching) is far less resource hogging than the example above

Comment: I wonder if the fact that the items remain highlighted as the cursor hovers over them (if you look at the video again) has something to do with it ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I get an overlay icon painted over both state icon and normal icon.  I can't figure out, also after reading the MS documentation, how I can change above code to only show the overlay over the normal icon and not over the state icon ... any idea how to ?